# Adding server-side validation causing exception when getting user list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Asp.net Core 3.1

I have extended IdentityUser and created ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [MaxLength ( 150 ) ] 
    public string FirstName { get ; set ; }
    [ MaxLength ( 150 ) ] 
    public string LastName { get ; set ; }
    public int AlternateUserId { get ; set ; }
    [ MaxLength ( 150 ) ] 
    public string CompanyName { get ; set ; }

    [ MaxLength ( 38 ) ] 
    [ Required ] 
    public string ClientId { get ; set ; }
    [ Required ] 
    public int ShortClient { set ; get ; }
    public bool  Locked { set ; get ; }
    public bool Admin { set ; get ; }
}
```

I created a migration updated the database which created all of the Aspuser...... tables.

I then scaffolded the database to get the crud controllers and views.

This gave me this partial class.

```
public partial class Aspnetusers
{
   public Aspnetusers()
   {
       Aspnetuserclaims = new HashSet<Aspnetuserclaims>();
       Aspnetuserlogins = new HashSet<Aspnetuserlogins>();
       Aspnetuserroles = new HashSet<Aspnetuserroles>();
       Aspnetusertokens = new HashSet<Aspnetusertokens>();
       Usertoroles = new HashSet<Usertoroles>();
   }
   [Key]
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an email.")]
   [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.")]
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
   public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
   public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
   public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
   public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
   //  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an email.")]
   public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
   public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
   public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
   public DateTime? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
   public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
   public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
   //  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the first name.")]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   //  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the last name.")]
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public int AlternateUserId { get; set; }
   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
   //   [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must choose a company")]
   public string ClientId { get; set; }
   public int ShortClient { get; set; }
   public bool Locked { get; set; }
   public bool Admin { set; get; }

   public virtual Company ShortClientNavigation { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Aspnetuserclaims> Aspnetuserclaims { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Aspnetuserlogins> Aspnetuserlogins { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Aspnetuserroles> Aspnetuserroles { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Aspnetusertokens> Aspnetusertokens { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Usertoroles> Usertoroles { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I have this controller

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly PCSLoginContext context;
    private ILogger<CompaniesController> logger;

    public UsersController(PCSLoginContext context,  ILogger<CompaniesController> logger)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.logger = logger ;
    }   
    // GET: Aspnetusers
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserIndex()
    {
       var users = _context.Aspnetusers.ToList ( ) ; 
       return View( users);
    }
}
```

Notice most of the [Required] decorations are commented out.

If I run the code as is the first line in the UserIndex() code runs fine ,gets a list of users  and sends them off to the view.

If I uncomment any of the commented out [Required] validation decorations then the code gets an exception in  the line

```
var users = _context.Aspnetusers.ToList ( ) ;
```

If I debug into MS code I found the exception

> '((System.Linq.IQueryable)collection).ElementType' threw an exception
>   of type 'System.NotImplementedException'

The logger gives back the exception

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.    at
>   MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\Row.cs:line 344
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line
>   272    at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader ,
>   ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   SextantCoreHostApp.Areas.Users.Controllers.UsersController.UserIndex()
>   in
>   C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Development\SextantCore3WithPermissions\SextantCoreHostApp\Areas\Users\Controllers\UsersController.cs:line
>   35    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
>   invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
>   isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
>   isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
>   middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext
>   context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
>   middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
>   middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field in your user table is returning null value (System.DBNull), so that cannot be assigned to a mandatory string property.

Comment: The fields that are being marked as required are not null.  The table only has one row of data in it.

Comment: I checked again and one of the fields in the row was null.  That fixed it. Thanks.